# If Condition Not Supported In DDL Triggers

Tags: sql-server, database, if-statement, triggers, ddl

I have a DDL trigger for monitoring the changes made to specific tables in SQL Server database. But it is not working. Surprising thing is that when I remove table filter (i.e. the IF statement) then it works. Even I tried by putting condition like 1 = 1, it also doesn't work. So my observation is IF condition is not working here for some reasons.
Please anybody help, what is going wrong here. Following is DDL trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [SQLObjectMonitoring]
ON DATABASE
FOR create_table, alter_table, drop_table
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @data XML = EVENTDATA()

    DECLARE @DatabaseName [varchar](256) = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]', 'varchar(256)')
    DECLARE @EventType [varchar](50) = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'varchar(50)')  -- value is case-sensitive
    DECLARE @ObjectName [varchar](256) = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'varchar(256)')
    DECLARE @ObjectType [varchar](25) = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectType)[1]', 'varchar(25)')
    DECLARE @SQLCommOR [varchar](max) = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommOR)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
    DECLARE @LoginName [varchar](256) = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]', 'varchar(256)')

    IF(@ObjectName = 'TABLE1' OR @ObjectName = 'TABLE2' OR @ObjectName = 'TABLE3' OR @ObjectName = 'TABLE4' OR @ObjectName = 'TABLE5')
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.SQLObjectLog(databasename, eventtype,objectname, objecttype, sqlcommOR, loginname, eventdate)
        VALUES(@DatabaseName, @EventType, @ObjectName, @ObjectType, @SQLCommOR, @LoginName, GETDATE())
    END
END
```

Comment: It is working fine [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=2511e15c48050e1101cc1646c6e6163a)

Comment: By what criteria are you determining that it's not working? That the data isn't being inserted into the table? It could be that the principal that executed the triggering event doesn't have insert permission on the dbo.SQLObjectLog table.

Comment: ...Or there is some kind of other problem like a PK violation...

Comment: Thanks @Lukasz Szozda for the suggestion. But I wonder why my trigger is not working on my system.

Comment: @Ben Thul, you guessed it right. It is not inserting the records to the table. But as I said, it works great when I remove IF condition. So I don't think that it is related to insert permissions.

Comment: The only thing that I can think of then is somehow @ObjectName doesn't hold what you think it does. In the interest of debugging, you're probably going to have to resort to the tried and true `print @ObjectName;` in the trigger. As an aside, using `@ObjectName in («list goes here»)` in your conditional is probably more readable and maintainable over time.

Comment: @BenThul I will check @ ObjectName value. Thanks for suggesting on readability and maintainability. I will definitely do the the changes.